# Automatically get sub parameters as string?

Tags: vb.net

This is a longshot, but I have to ask...

I try to write a generic exceptionhandler for my entire app.

So when there's an exception, I catch it ... but I would like to add all the parameters as string to my handler.

Take this sample...

```
Sub SomeSub(server As String, database As String, table As String) 
    Try
        ' Bla Bla exception
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim exx As New MyExceptionHandler(ex)
        exx.AddParameters() ' <- can I add all parameters as string automatically?
    End Try
End Sub
```

I don't want to do this..

```
exx.AddParameter("server", server)
exx.AddParameter("database", database)
exx.AddParameter("table", table)
```

I just want to do something like...

```
exx.AddParameters()
```

and then the function must find out itself which parameters there is in the sub and add them as string.

Is that possible?

:)

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this repeatedly in many different try/catch blocks?  It doesn't sound like a good use of exception handling...

Comment: it might be possible - what is  `MyExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to get the parameter **names** through Reflection but it's not possible to get the parameter **values**.

A low-impact way to accomplish this would be to create a Dictionary object as the first task in each method that contains parameter names and values.

If you give this Dictionary object a consistent name, you could standardize the exception handler.

Comment: Ok thanks - I was expecting this, but I had hopes :)